# ClearInterval remove or not the calling event JS

Tags: javascript, html, events, settimeout, setinterval

So, I have a script with a lot of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

My problem is when I use the `clearInterval` method, I want to know if the method stop the function after firing or if the method delete definitely the firing event. It is very important for me to know that because if the `clearInterval` do not delete the firing event, the computer continue to call a lot of events that can slow down the computer.

My code is a bit long to be listed fully in this post, but I use `setInterval` like this:

```
teste = [];
teste.push (window.setInterval (function () {Do stuff...}, 20));
  // The same for window.setTimeout();
```

The firing `clearInterval` method can block:

```
window.setInterval (function () {
  /*Here after firing or can stop the firing event*/
  Do stuff...
}, 20);
```

And I remove `setInterval` like this:

```
window.clearInterval (teste [teste.length-1]);   // The same for window.clearTimeout ();
```

Any help is appreciated,

*Tell me if you have some questions or comments.*

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post a complete copy of the code you are talking about and not a paraphrased version? For instance, when/where are you calling `clearInterval`?

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "if the method stop the function after firing or if the method delete definitely the firing event"; could you explain the difference again? You seem to be worried that the callback you passed to `setInterval` will continue to be invoked after you called `clearInterval` - that shouldn't happen unless you're not passing the right interval ID. If that's indeed the problem, I suggest you post an example demonstrating this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would use a different approach here:

```
var queue = [];

function prepare (fx, delay, repeated) {
  return {
    fx: fx,
    at: new Date().getTime() + delay,
    repeated: !!repeated
  }
}

queue.push(prepare(function () {…}, 20));
.
queue.push(prepare(function () {…}, 20), true);
.
.
.

window.setTimeout(function check() {
  var now = new Date().getTime(), 
            newQueue = [], 
            i = 0, entry;

  for (; i < queue.length; i++) {
    entry = queue[i];

    if (entry.at <= now) {
      entry.fx();

      if (entry.repeated) newQueue.push(entry);

    } else {
      newQueue.push(entry);
    }
  }

  queue = newQueue;
  window.setTimeout(check, 1);

}, 1);
```

That way you have only one timer/interval running and so full control over what was called and will be called. Additionally there wont be any issues with the JS Event Queue which might run in time or not.